# Vectorize the generation of a 3D matrix made within a loop up to now

Tags: matlab, matrix, spatial-interpolation

Up to now, I used 3 loops to build a matrix, but it takes such a long time that I would like to vectorize it. But either it's not possible, or I took the wrong way to do it. Anyway, I am in front of a wall, and I need your help.

Here are the loops :

```
AngleList = [0 : 10 : 300];            % 31 elements
```

Fx_mat is a (1000,120,31) matrix, 31 is for the 31 elements corresponding to AngleList.

```
for Aaa = 1:Nb_loop1                   % Nb_loop1 = 3
    for Bbb = 1:Nb_loop2               % Nb_loop2 = 120
        for Ccc = 1:Nb_loop3           % Nb_loop3 = 1000
            Angle = rand()*300;        % Then Angle is between 0 and 300
            Fx_mat_interp(Aaa,Bbb,Ccc) = interp1(AngleList, Fx_mat(Ccc,Bbb,:), Angle);
        end
    end
end
```

---

What I first tried to do is to create matrix with my datas :

```
m_Angle     = rand(Nb_loop3,Nb_loop2)*300         % 1000x120 matrix
m_AngleList = permute(reshape(repmat(AngleList,Nb_loop3,Nb_loop2),Nb_loop1,Nb_loop3,Nb_loop2),[1 3 2]);
                       % I repeat my AngleList vector in a 1000x120x31 matrix
for Aaa = 1:Nb_loop1
   Fx_mat_interp(Aaa,:,:) = ?????(m_AngleList, Fx_mat(Nb_loop3,Nb_loop2,:), m_Angle);
end
```

I would like to replace ????? with the equivalent to interp1, but I can't find it.

Do you have any idea to help me please ?

P.S: And a lot of great thinks for all of you for this new year.

Comment: You did first try the loop method with preallocation of `Fx_mat_interp` using `zeros` right???

Comment: Right, I just didn't add the beginning of my program not to load my question...
Here is a correction on my question, at the end, you must read :
 Fx_mat_interp(Aaa,:,:) = ?????(m_AngleList, Fx_mat(:,:,:), m_Angle);